# Xubuntu Linux 22.04: "sudo apt update" does not work

Tags: apt, updates, xubuntu, sudo

Hello Linux Community,

I am having an issue with my "sudo apt update" command. When I run it, it gives me error messages stating that a jammy Release does not have a release file. I am fairly new to using Linux, is there something I can do to fix this issue?

(The site won't let me post an image, so here is the error message I get):

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `nilarimogard/webupd8` PPA, which does not support your version of Ubuntu.

Run the command `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` to remove the PPA.

None of the webupd8 PPAs are active anymore.

Comment: Thank you! That has solved my issue